# I want to build a search engine with Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I want to build a search engine with Solr/Lucene. Shall I use for that Apache Solr 3 or 4 (I think in this context Solr=Lucene)? Furthermore, I have the Lucene in Action, 2nd Edition (for Lucene 3) from 2010. Is this book already obsolete? Which books do you recommend for beginners?

Comment: Solr != Lucene.  Solr is a search server that uses the Lucene library.  Lucene in Action 2nd ed. is the latest edition, to my knowledge.  It's a fine resource.  Some things have changed in Lucene 4.0, and you might do well to be mindful of that, but shouldn't be difficult to adjust.  Up to you which version you use.  I'd be inclined to start with the latest, but that's me.

Answer (score 5):

**1)  Shall I use for that Apache Solr 3 or 4**

Always use the latest stable version. There's a lot of performance improvements in the latest version.

**2) I think in this context Solr=Lucene**

No, both are different. Solr is a HTTP wrapper around Lucene. Solr is like a web application with search feature built using Lucene, and [with a lot of additional features.](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html)

**3) I have the Lucene in Action, 2nd Edition (for Lucene 3) from 2010. Is this book already obsolete?**

I follow the same book. That's not obsolete. It gives you a decent overview (expert level in fact) on entire framework.

**What you you've to do to keep yourself up-to-date is**

a) Explore [Lucene 4 new features.](http://bed-con.org/images/files/bed2011/bed2011-whatsnewinlucene4.pdf) Try searching for Lucene 4 vs Lucene 3 articles on the web.

b) Follow Lucene in Action 2's [author's blog](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/).